What hot keys actually work with Bookworm?
I recently got a Raspberry Pi 5 pre-loaded with the Raspberry Pi OS and I'm new to RPis in general. I have some experience using Linux.
I was having trouble understanding why certain hot keys (reference) didn't seem to be working, e.g. Ctrl+Alt+T for Terminal, and then why the menu item for "Setup Hot Keys" was enabled in the "Main Menu Editor" but not actually appearing in the Main Menu. One thing led to another and I have come to believe that this is mostly because I'm on the Bookworm variant of Raspberry Pi OS, which uses Wayland/Wayfire by default.
I've been looking at the Wayfire tutorial and it seems like some of hotkeys specified in the default key-bindings work, e.g. Alt+Escape and Super+W, but not others, e.g. Super+Enter, Super+Tab, Super+E, etc.
Looking at the doc on bindings available by default, I think that the plugins that support these keybinds probably need to be activated since the default wayfire.ini provided by RP OS is pretty bare (basically just the input and output sections) and it doesn't look like I have any other wayfire.ini in my paths. However, I'm also still confused because certain key-bindings like Alt+Escape and Alt+Tab are under the fast-switcher and switcher plugins respectively and work, even though those plugins are not enabled in my wayfire.ini.
So, my questions are:

Is it right to say that wayfire.ini is what primarily controls hot keys for RP OS Bookworm?
Is there a reference for which key-bindings/plugins are currently supported?
Are there certain key-bindings/plugins that have been disabled for RP OS and are not compatible at the moment?
Is the there a risk/concern to enabling any of the plugins for RP OS?
Is the main reason these plugins aren't enabled by default due to performance concerns?

